# Passing list of values to SELECT PostgreSQL query in Haskell

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I'm studying PostgreSQL with Haskell with this lib: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:query

While I could select an user like this:

```
  (query_ conn "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NAME == john" :: IO [Only Int]) >>= mapM_ print
```

using `query_`:

```
query_ :: FromRow r => Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
```

I think I should use `query`:

```
query :: (ToRow q, FromRow r) => Connection -> Query -> q -> IO [r]
```

to pass a list of values. However, how do I pass this list?

For example, for `INSERT`, I was able to do this:

```
(execute conn "INSERT INTO users (NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (?,?)") (["john", "123456"]::[String]) >>= print
```

but what is the equivalent for `SELECT`?

Comment: there is no example on what you want to do with your *SELECT* but yes you should use `query` as you did use `execute` - usually you'll pass a tuple with the values that should go in the `?` parameters - lists are more for combinators like [`In`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:In) - can you add the SELECT-Statement you want to query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, since you ask about lists and I don't see how they enter into the picture. But the parameterized version of your select query is this:

```
query conn "SELECT * FROM users where NAME == ?" (Only ("john" :: String))
```

Comment: Why the same does not work for `execute conn "drop table if exists ?" (Only ("users"::String))` with `SqlError {sqlState = "42601", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "syntax error at or near \"'users'\"", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Because `String`s get quoted to produce SQL strings. That query becomes `drop table if exists 'users'` after the substitution, not the `drop table if exists users` that you were hoping for. Poke around in the library's newtypes -- there's one for including things without quoting. (I'd link to it, but Hackage is down at the moment.) That said... are you *sure* you need to dynamically choose which table gets deleted? That sounds like a very unusual way to use a database.

Comment: I don't need a dynamic lib name, I was just testing things/ Why escaping works for `SELECT` but not for `DROP`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You are mistaken. You wouldn't be able to dynamically choose a table that way with `select`, either. Try it: `query conn "SELECT * FROM ? where NAME == 'john'" (Only ("users" :: String))`. You will get an error. If your question is why it works for the `john` bit, well... because that's a hole that expects a SQL string!

Comment: Ok but now I'm confused about how `?` works. It only works for when a value is expected to be filled dinamically?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're confused to me! But if you have further questions, it's probably best to 1. spend a little time with the documentation and the REPL figuring out precisely what's confusing and 2. write up the details in a fresh question post here on SO.